# touchUpInside event not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3, selector

I'm new to IOS programming , but strangely same code works in a different class so I don't have any idea why isn't it working
It's in Swift 3

```
class BottomMenu : NSObject{

    //Container view
    var bottomView: UIView!    

    //Button
    var buttonContents : UIButton!


    init(bottomView : UIView) {
        super.init()
        self.bottomView = bottomView        

        buttonContents = UIButton(frame: getFrame(index: 0))    
        buttonContents.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue //To see where to click on the screen
        bottomView.addSubview(buttonContents)

        buttonContents.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func getFrame(index : CGFloat!) -> CGRect{
        let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        return CGRect(x: (screenW/3) * index,
                           y: 0,
                           width: screenW/3,
                           height: self.bottomView.frame.size.height)
    }    
    func onClick(sender: UIButton!){
        NSLog("click")
    }

}
```

here's the implementation of this class :

```
let bottomMenu = BottomMenu(bottomView: bottomNavBarContainer)
```

So, the "click" log never shows

Comment: Please add swift version to tags.

Comment: yes, Sorry, it's Swift 3

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine in Playground. The error must be in the usage of the class. Parent view has userInteraction disabled or such.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

class BottomMenu : NSObject{

//Container view
var bottomView: UIView!

//Button
var buttonContents : UIButton!


init(bottomView : UIView) {
    super.init()
    self.bottomView = bottomView

    buttonContents = UIButton(frame: getFrame(index: 0))
    buttonContents.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue //To see where to click on the screen
    bottomView.addSubview(buttonContents)

    buttonContents.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func getFrame(index : CGFloat!) -> CGRect{
    let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGRect(x: (screenW/3) * index,
                  y: 0,
                  width: screenW/3,
                  height: self.bottomView.frame.size.height)
}
func onClick(sender: UIButton!){
    NSLog("click")
}

}

var container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
container.addSubview(view)
let buttonContents = BottomMenu(bottomView: view)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

NSObject is not a UIResponder, so it cannot process UIEvent. A solution could be to make the class descend from UIView instead of NSObject or exposing the button to add the target inside of a ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `#selector(onClick)` indicates a function with no parameters. Your onClick function has a single parameter, so the selector should be `#selector(onClick(sender:))`. At least I think that's the selector format in Swift 3. I'm Still getting used to Swift selector syntax.

Comment: thanks, but click event is still not being triggered

Comment: I just tested it and the syntax I outlined worked. There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3** adaptation, there are two main changes when adding a target.

1. Change your `selector` to

   ```
   buttonContents.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BottomMenu.onClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   ```
2. Add underscore to the method

   ```
   func onClick(_ sender: UIButton!){
   ```

Just to clarify:

```
class BottomMenu : NSObject{

    //Container view
    var bottomView: UIView!    

    //Button
    var buttonContents : UIButton!


    init(bottomView : UIView) {
        super.init()
        self.bottomView = bottomView        

        buttonContents = UIButton(frame: getFrame(index: 0))    
        buttonContents.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue //To see where to click on the screen
        bottomView.addSubview(buttonContents)

        buttonContents.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func getFrame(index : CGFloat!) -> CGRect{
        let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        return CGRect(x: (screenW/3) * index,
                           y: 0,
                           width: screenW/3,
                           height: self.bottomView.frame.size.height)
    }    
    func onClick(_ sender: UIButton!){
        NSLog("click")
    }

}
```

Comment: this code doesn't trigger click as well.. in other class it works just fine, but not here..

Comment: Thats because the assigned `#selector()` is wrong. Try things listed in answer. That will work.

Comment: Pretty sure about the underscore. This error only pops out in runtime. I am not sure for the reason otherwise.

Comment: this is what code looks now :
buttonContents.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BottomMenu.onClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    func onClick(_ sender: UIButton!){
        NSLog("click")
    }

Comment: No. Change the actual `onClick(sender: UIButton!)` to  `onClick(_ sender: UIButton!)`

Comment: I changed . Still the same .maybe you could connect to me via TeamViewer? beacause all theese variants doesn't work

Comment: for some reason I can't copy here the "_" symbol)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128820/discussion-between-user2976267-and-idan).